# .NET PackagePart object - what does it contain?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, compression, zip

What does a PackagePart object include ? Does it contain the actual data of the file associated to it or just the Uri, content type and compression option?

Answer (score 0):

The `PackagePart` gives you access to its contained data using one of the `GetStream()` overloads, as a `Stream` (obviously). Depending on the concrete implementation, you could also get the data directly, from the `Uri` property, but using the packaging API is a simpler, more general way to do this without your client code needing to know anything about the underlying backing store for the package (e.g. the package doesn't have to be a zip file, it could be a web service).